# Legend text color doesn't change

Tags: r, plot, legend, textcolor, density-plot

I've used this code

```
plot.ecdf(subset(d.pizza, area == "Camden")$delivery_min, 
          col = "red", main = "ECDF for pizza deliveries")
plot.ecdf(subset(d.pizza, area == "Westminster")$delivery_min, 
          add = TRUE, col = "blue")
plot.ecdf(subset(d.pizza, area == "Brent")$delivery_min, 
          add = TRUE, col = "green")
legend(x=50, y=0.4, legend=c("Camden", "Westiminster", "Brent"), col=c("red","blue","green") )
```

to get this plot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY2QW.jpg)

but as you see legend text doesn't match colors I wrote in the code. Why? How can I fix it?

Same thing about this code

```
plot(density(subset(d.pizza, area == "Camden")$delivery_min), col="red", ylim=c(0,0.06)) 
  lines(density(subset([d.pizza, area == "Westminster")$delivery_min), col="blue") 
  lines(density(subset(d.pizza, area == "Brent")$delivery_min), col="green")
legend(x=50, y=0.05, legend=c("Camden", "Westiminster", "Brent"), col=c("red","blue","green") )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKyIR.jpg)

Must be doing the same mistake..
Thanks in advance!

d.pizza id a data frame from "DescTools" package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1:   use fill instead of col

```
legend(x=50, y=0.4, legend=c("Camden", "Westiminster", "Brent"), 
   fill=c("red","blue","green") )
```

Solution 2:   use pch

```
legend(x=50, y=0.4, legend=c("Camden", "Westiminster", "Brent"), 
   col=c("red","blue","green"), pch=16 )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a type of symbol to be drawn in the legend, so that it can be colored:

```
legend(x=50, y=0.4, legend=c("Camden", "Westiminster", "Brent"), col=c("red","blue","green"), pch=1) #pch sets the type of point to be drawn
```